# Minecraft PE Item addon

Tags: minecraft, add-on, minecraft-forge

I was trying to make custom item in minecraft pocket edition i tried everything correctly but didn't worked, the addon successfully get installed in mcpe but doesn't show the item in game
[here you can check the addon](http://www.filedropper.com/item) please help me fix it

Comment: Wow, everything is wrong with this question. First of all, Forge is only for Java Edition, so you're obviously not using it for Pocket Edition. You're not supposed to spam unrelated tags. Second of all, you need to post all of the details about your problem in the question itself - that is, you must not make us download a file from a random file host to have any idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica are you familiar with Minecraft bedrock, if yes i'll explain everything

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica nvm brother, the addon is working only i gotta do is turn on experimental gameplay btw how can i make the addon which don't need experimental gameplay cus, i've created a custom mob in it (without replacing other mob) and it doesn't need experimental gameplay

Answer (score 0):

I think the entity will show up without experimental gameplay if you just use 'is_experimental:false'.

[image: Here's an example :]